# PTIJ: Donuts on Chanukah with one's car

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Can one fulfill the Chiyuv to have donuts on Chanukah with one's car, by making [donuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doughnut_%28driving%29?wprov=sfla1)?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but the engine must be filled with olive oil, instead of the nasty stuff which mechanics put into it nowadays.

Ideally, this should be done in a fancy car, with expensive clothes and while shouting out "such shall be done to the man whom the king wishes to honor!"

It is my belief that this is common practice already among donut-makers.

Answer (score 3):

The Mishna (Taanis 3:8) delineates the proper methods in which one can encircle oneself.
The donut can only be carried out using the same methods which were available in that time, namely, a stick.

> עג עוגה ועמד בתוכה
>
> Draw a circle and stand within it.